# Vue 2 to Vue 3 migration (Vuetify 2 to Vuetify 3)

Tags: webpack, vuejs2, migration, vuejs3, vuetify.js

I need some general advice on migration.

This is my 1st time working doing a migration and working with webpack.

This my package.json. Do you think it's possible/ worth it to migrate to Vue 3 / Vuetify 3.
Would it make my life a lot more easier if I used Vite instead of Webpack?

I attach my package.json so you can take a quick look.

I just need some general advice on my approach not a solution.

```
{
  "name": "hackair",
  "version": "2.1.2",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@vue/compat": "^3.3.4",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "dayjs": "^1.10.4",
    "eslint-plugin-vuetify": "^2.0.1",
    "highcharts": "^9.1.0",
    "highcharts-vue": "^1.3.5",
    "leaflet": "^1.6.0",
    "leaflet-gesture-handling": "^1.2.2",
    "leaflet.wms": "^0.2.0",
    "vue": "^3.3.4",
    "vue-i18n": "^9.2.2",
    "vue-loader": "^15.10.1",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.7.14",
    "vue-toastification": "^2.0.0-rc.5",
    "vue-ua": "^1.7.0",
    "vue2-leaflet": "^2.7.1",
    "vuelidate": "^0.7.6",
    "vuetify": "^3.3.2",
    "vuex": "^4.0.0",
    "webpack": "^4.46.0",
    "webpack-plugin-vuetify": "^2.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.13.1",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.4.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^5.0.8",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.4.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~4.4.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^4.5.13",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.3.4",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^6.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^8.41.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.3",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.20.0",
    "eslint-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "prettier": "^1.19.1",
    "sass": "~1.32.6",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "speed-measure-webpack-plugin": "^1.5.0",
    "vue-cli-plugin-axios": "0.0.4",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "~2.0.6"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/vue3-essential",
      "eslint:recommended",
      "@vue/prettier"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    },
    "rules": {
      "no-console": 0,
      "no-unused-vars": 0,
      "no-debugger": 0,
      "vue/no-unused-components": 0,
      "vue/valid-v-slot": [
        "error",
        {
          "allowModifiers": true
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead"
  ]
}
```

In general I follow the Vue 3 migration build and updating one dependency at a time which by themselves lead to other dependencies updates.

Changing a single dependency seems to trigger a chain reaction on other dependency upgrades. Is that normal? Seems very frustrating and tedious and I am wondering if I am doing it the correct way.

I was expecting o more straightforward way to migrate. It feels like there is no correct approach and not a specific place to start.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes it's not straightforward and very frustrating.
Many of Vuetify 2 components are missing in vuetify 3.
I guess it's easier to rewrite the whole app.

Comment: True story, forget it. Vuetify 2 to 3 is a nightmare, they broke it.

Comment: I'm in the same boat. What did you end up doing?

Comment: @Sarah We gave it to externals, which took them more than a week just to update the dependencies and make any necessary breaking changes inside the code (such as imports etc). Still in options API but that's expected. 

In general, it's a slow and difficult process, especially if the project is quite old.